# SQL Server Transaction Replication on different versions of Windows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

Currently we use SQL Server 2014 Transaction Replication in Windows Server 2012 (both Publisher and Subscriber are on different servers with the same operating system).

We need to add a new subscriber, and my question is this: do we need to have the same operating system for the newly added subscriber, i.e. Windows Server 2012, or can I use the Windows 7 operating system.

Note : Both Publisher and Subscriber are in two different domains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server replication on different Windows versions.  What is more important is the version of SQL Server.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2016/08/12/suppported-sql-server-versions-in-replication-topology/

Comment: Thanks for quick response, will proceed accordingly and let you know if i face any problem while creating subscriber. Regards,
Uday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transactional replication between SQL Servers regardless of the operating system you are using, but I would like to make the remark that, since you are talking about Windows 7 isn't necessarily a supported operating system.

See for example [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2014](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx) where you will notice that Windows 7 is in the supported operating systems for Standard edition but not for Enterprise edition.

You might want to keep that in mind.